# Matlab operation on anonymous functions

Tags: matlab

I have two anonymous functions f and g and I need to compute the integral over f*g using the quad function.

I tried the following which didnt not work:

```
h=@(x)(f(x)*g(x))
quad(h,-1,1);
```

Is there any way to make this work ?

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

It depends on how `f` and `g` are defined, but you probably just need to add a dot:

```
h = @(x) f(x).*g(x);
```

### Long answer

According to [`quad`'s documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad.html),

> Q = quad(FUN,A,B)
>
> [...] The function Y=FUN(X) should accept a vector argument X and return a vector result Y, the integrand evaluated at each element of X.

Assuming `f` and `g` already satisfy this requirement, `h` should be defined with `.*` ([element-wise multiplication](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)) so that it will fulfill it too.

Example:

```
>> f = @(x) x;
>> g = @(x) x.^2;
>> h = @(x) f(x).*g(x);
>> quad(h, 0, 1)
ans =
   0.250000000000000
```